# Matrix is rank deficient, Multiple Linear Regression Accord.NET

Tags: c#, linear-regression, accord.net

I'm working with Multiple Linear Regression in C# using Accord.NET, I followed the example, the method needs 2 arguments inputs which is a 2d array, and outputs which is a 1d array, the two arrays must have the same length.

```
 public static double[] RegressionLineaire(double[][]input,double[]output)
    {
        double[] coeff = new double[40];
        var ols = new OrdinaryLeastSquares();
        {
            ols.UseIntercept = true;
        };
        Console.WriteLine("inputs length = " + input.Length + " outputs 
        length = " + output.Length);
        MultipleLinearRegression regression = ols.Learn(input, output);
        
        coeff = regression.Weights;

        return coeff;
    }
```

the inputs and outputs have the same length but I get this exception

> System.InvalidOperationException : 'Matrix is rank deficient.'

Comment: Check if your input satisfies conditions [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)).

Answer (score 5):

I just found a solution to the problem, it was not a input shape issue, and i don't know what is exatly the cause of the matrix is rank deficient exception, but i managed de make it work by adding this line.

```
var ols = new OrdinaryLeastSquares();
    {
        ols.UseIntercept = true;
        ols.IsRobust = true;
    };
```